# Decorator not work with argument suggestions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

decorator code:

```
from functools import wraps
def wrap2(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

test function :

```
@wrap2
def f2(x='', y=''):
    return 1

def f3(x='', y=''):
    return 1
```

problem: can not use arguments suggestion with `tab` key on decorated function.

screenshot:
[image]
[image]

great thanks

Comment: After decorating it, your function has the signature `f2(*args, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the decorator can only keep the doctoring the same even if you use `functools.wraps`, but can not keep the signature of your original function.